# Installing GIMP: snap, repository, or PPA?

Tags: ppa, snap, gimp

I haven't been keeping up with the snapstorm, and now I'm faced with a decision I'm ill-prepared to make: what is the best way to install GIMP on Ubuntu 17.04?

I'm offered two choices by the Ubuntu Software app:

1. GIMP 2.8.22 from Snapcraft
2. GIMP 2.8.20-1 from the Ubuntu

If I select the newer, Snapcraft version, I'm then asked to authenticate at the Snap Store, and I'm a bit unwilling to register for new stuff I may not  need later.

There's also the option of GIMP's own PPA.

So, what is the preferred way to do this?

Comment: It is your choice.

Comment: I use the gimp version from the repository. If you have the time, you can try all the alternatives in a live or persistent live system before you decide  what you want to install in your main system.

Comment: You left out another option: https://bintray.com/package/files/probono/AppImages/GIMP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd probably be better and more consistent support by using tested apps from the repository.  Many people (including me) use PPA's for certain of our preferred apps.

When you choose a PPA then you'll have to remember which PPA's are using and be prepared to use the developers of the PPA for ultimate support.

You can get general support for common PPA's from regular Ubuntu support communities.  But if a PPA fails, or you discover some conflict with your PPA and Ubuntu, you may have to be prepared to remove the PPA, then check and verify your Ubuntu installation.  Then reinstall the PPA and rely on the PPA community to fix what might be a conflict.

Keep in mind the repository is tested by the community and not expected to present any problems.  If there is a problem with the application in the repository, the Ubuntu developers will work to resolve it or remove it from the repository.

Comment: Repository > PPA, agreed. Especially for hassle-free existence. What's your view on Snap vs. Repository?